# Не всегда срабатывает readyread()

Tags: c++, qt, udp

Отправляю с одного компьютера на другой большой файл:

```
QFile file(filename)
if(file.isOpen(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
{
    quint64 bytesAvialable = file.bytesAvialable();
    while(bytesAvialable > 1024)
    {
        char buf[1024];
        file.read(buf, 1024);
        QByteArray dataBuff, dataOut;
        databuff.append(buf, sizeof(buf));
       
        QDataStream stream(&dataOut, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
        stream.setByteOrder(QDataStream::BigEndian);
        stream.writeRawData(dataBuff.data(), dataBuff.size());
        emit signalReadyData(dataOut);
        bytesAvialable -= dataBuff.size();
    }
    file.close();
}
```

Но на стороне приёмника получаю меньшее число пакетов, нежели было отправлено. Например, если отправить 6000000 пакетов, на стороне приёмника будет 5500000 пакетов. При этом, пакеты не попадают в очередь, так как на стороне приёмника в слоте:

```
slotReadyRead()
{
    qDebug() << socket->bytesAvialable();
    while(socket->hasPendingDatagrams());
    {
        QByteArray datagram;
        datagram.resize(socket->pendingDatagramSize());
        socket->readDatagram(datagram.data(), datagram.size());
        emit signalReadyData(datagram);
    }
}
```

`socket->bytesAvialable()` показывает число, равное размеру одного пакета.
Пробовал увеличить очередь с помощью `sysctl -w net.core.rmem_default = 26214400` и `sysctl -w net.core.rmem_max = 26214400`, но не помогло. При этом, если уменьшать скорость выдачи пакетов(например, с помощью `thread.usleep(1)`, то количество отправленных и полученных пакетов совпадает. Вопрос в следующем: из-за чего `readyRead()` может не испускаться при приёме пакета и как можно увеличить скорость обработки получаемых пакетов, так как мне кажется, что `readyRead()` не успевает срабатывать из-за этого.

Comment: *"Отправляю с одного компьютера на другой "* - в вопросе этого кода нет. Как нет и кода использования UDP. И для справки - UDP не гарантирует ни доставку, ни порядок пакетов, так что при его использовании следует быть готовым к потере и/или перемешиванию всех пакетов.

Comment: Отправка по сигналу signalReadyData(), в слоте просто writeDatagram(). Про то, что не гарантирует доставку я знаю, вопрос в том, из-за чего эти пакеты могут не доставляться. Из за высокой скорости выдачи или из-за низкой скорости обработки.

Comment: Из-за чего угодно. Может и из-за не самой оптимальной длины дейтаграммы, может и из-за общей загруженности сети.